# Checking all immediate child checkboxes onclicking parent checkbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a list in my html code where onclick of parent checkbox, the immediate child checkboxes should be checked.

```
<ul class="test_ex">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref">Fruits</a>
        <ul class="example">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Apple </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Orange </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="test_ex_sample">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref">Birds</a>
                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref"> Peacock </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Parrot </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="example">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="parent" onchange="fnTest(this);" /> <a class="ref"> Food </a>
                        <ul class="example">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chckBox" class="child" /> <a class="ref">Bread </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried many ways to check only the immediate children. But none of them worked.
These are few ways:

- Tried using .siblings() [Found this solution on stackoverflow only]

  ```
  function fnTest(check) {

    if ($(check).is(':checked')) {
      $(check).siblings('.example').find('.child').attr("checked", true);
    } else {
      $(check).siblings('.example').find('.child').attr("checked", false);
    }
  }
  ```

[Fiddle demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/20/)

Here the first list works properly. Again when clicked on second list it checks the 3rd list children too.

- Secondly tried this set of code
  Tried using the class which is checked annd getting children from that class. This checks all parents that belong to that class.

[Fiddle demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/21/)

```
function fnTest(check) {
    if ($(check).is(':checked')) {
        var classParent = "." + $(check).attr('class');
        $(classParent).attr("checked", true);
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: you should have unique id for elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your first try of using siblings(). You can change to the following:

```
function fnTest(check){

    if($(check).is(':checked')){
        $(check).siblings('.example:first').find('.child').prop("checked",true);
    }
    else{
        $(check).siblings('.example:first').find('.child').prop("checked",false);        
    }
      }
```

By using this it checks only the first children. And also change your .attr to .prop

here is a demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/51/)

Comment: Most relevant and a perfect solution. It works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using jQuery. First of all remove `onchange="fnTest(this);"` from parent checkbox. Bind change event for parent checkbox like below :

```
$(function(){
   $('.parent').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.example:first .child').prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked'));
   });
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/49/)**

Comment: I used binding event and tried. It doesnt work. So i used onchange. Fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/34/

Comment: This works! But it doesnt work the second time. As in once i check parent then uncheck it and again check it back it doesnt work.

Comment: yeah I saw that, for this i updated using `.attr` to `.prop`. check updated answer and link

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 function fnTest(check) {
      $(check).closest("ul").find(":checkbox").prop("checked",check.checked);

}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/44/)

If you want only direct children  use like this

```
function fnTest(check) {
    $(check).closest("li").find(".example:first").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", check.checked);

}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/50/)

NOTE : use latest version in jquery, and also id should be unique

Comment: This checks all the checkboxes. I want only the immediate children to be checked sir.

Comment: @user3201640 could you tell me example for this

Answer (score 0):

// OK tested

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('li input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    var sibs = false;
    $(this).closest('ul').children('li').each(function () {
        if($('input[type=checkbox]', this).is(':checked')) sibs=true;
    })
    $(this).parents('ul').prev().prop('checked', sibs);
});});
```